# Thunk chaining within a thunk (using Redux toolkit). How to call a thunk when another one finished?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

My application allows users to enter data in many different places, and each time I use something like this to call an async thunk:

```
dispatch(handleDataEntry({ key, value })
```

In some cases the results of the API call inform the application that another datapoint needs to be set client-side, so the downstream `extraReducer` in my slice (using `createSlice` from `@reduxjs/toolkit`) should now re-dispatch the thunk.  But this seems to be an anti-pattern, and in any case I couldn't find a way to do this, so I'm storing `sideEffectKey` and `sideEffectValue` in state and having components in cases of non-nullity dispatch the thunk themselves.

This doesn't seem like a good solution, and in fact since `sideEffectKey` and `sideEffectValue` stay non-null until the second API call completes and I can clear them, `handleDataEntry` gets dispatched multiple times, causing me problems.

What's a better solution?  Is there some way to do something like this?

```
[handleDataEntry.fulfilled.toString()]: (
            state: Store,
            action: {
                payload: {
                    sideEffectKey: string | null
                    sideEffectValue: string | null
                }
            }
) => {
  if (action.payload.sideEffectKey) { 
     dispatch(handleDataEntry({ key: sideEffectKey, value: sideEffectValue }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if https://stackoverflow.com/a/73054252/7618742 helped you

Comment: Does it solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to dispatch a thunk when another one is finished ?

#### How to listen to a thunk status ?

In your case when you thunk is finish and succeed you dispatch `fulfilled` event.

Because create async thunk create actions for theses 3 different states:

- pending
- fulfilled
- rejected

By default your thunk cannot listen theses actions dispatched by your other thunk. You need a listener middleware to do it

### [Listener middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware)

With listener middleware you can listen to any actions to execute some logic.

You have three different way to listen:

- one with an `actionCreator`
- one with a `matcher`
- one with a `predicate`

#### How to use listener middleware ?

In your case you can add a matcher on this to execute handleDataEntry when it has finished.

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: handleDataEntry.fulfilled,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
     if (action.payload.sideEffectKey) { 
        listenerApi.dispatch(handleDataEntry({ key: sideEffectKey, value: sideEffectValue }))
     }
    }
  },
})
```

### Final note

Just be careful on your case you thunk your thunk to call it itself maybe ad a limit. To make sure to do not have an infinite fetch calls

### Avoiding side effect in reducers

You are right reducers must be pure and should not have side effects.